# What is the out voltage in figure B and why?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electric-circuits, voltage

What is the voltage in the second diagram and why?

I can not see really how to think about it there. I understand A and C I think (which are the same), because the voltage would have to be the same than the + side of the battery.

How do you think about it?

[image: voltage]

Comment: What is the voltage of the `-` side of the battery? `out` is directly connected to it in the "pressed" figure..

Comment: But isnt it also directly connected to the + side? @SolomonSlow

Comment: No. There is a resistor between `out` and the `+` terminal of the battery.

Comment: Yes so there is some drop, but not to 0, why do we assume so? @SolomonSlow

Comment: For one thing, because it's connected to ground. "Ground" _means_ 0V.

Comment: @SolomonSlow but it is also connected to the 9v pole

Comment: No. `out` is not connected to `+v`. When people here say "connected," they mean _directly_ connected. Two circuit elements that are connected to each other must always be at the same voltage. The two ends of the resistor are _not_ "connectced to" each other in that sense. The two ends of the resistor can be at different voltages, and _will_ be at different voltages when the button is pressed. The bottom end of the resistor and `out` and the `-` end of the battery and ground all are connected to each other. All must be at the same voltage...

Comment: ...And, _by definition_ whatever is connected to ground must be at 0V because that's what "ground" means: It means, "all other voltages in the circuit should be reported relative to this node."

Comment: If you know the battery voltage, $V$, and you know the value of the resistor, $R$, then you can calculate the current that must flow when the button is pressed, $I$, by using Ohm's Law: $I=V/R$

Comment: Yes, but "it is because i say" if you say "it is because ground is 0 and it is connected to the ground" there is no way I cant see that. I just do not think it is correct, or a solid reasoning. And for me, does not really help or answer anything. I am asking exactly why, that is the question. I can see that there will be a voltage drop if I just repeat what is out there, but not why the voltage will be 0. If you do not find the question reasonable, then just leave it. @SolomonSlow

Comment: Don't take my word for it. Find a textbook.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The voltage of a battery only tells about the difference in voltage between its terminals. Since one of its terminals is always connected to ground we know the negative terminal is at zero volt. If the battery is rated at, let's say, 9V then we know that the positive terminal is at +9V.

When the switch is pressed, the out-voltage reader is directly connected to ground. This means the out-voltage is at zero volt, since any part that is connected through wire (so no resistance) is always at the same voltage. In this case there is a voltage drop of 9V over the resistor. So before the resistor it is +9V and after the resistor the wire is at zero volt.

When the switch is released, the out-voltage is no longer connected to ground. It is only connected to the positive terminal through R1. Eventually, the out-voltage will reach +9V. The way to see this is to use the water analogy. We imagine the wires as canals, the resistors as dams which let a small amount of water through, the water level is voltage and the battery is a pump which always keeps the same difference in water level between its two terminals.

When the circuit is closed there is a 9 volt difference between the two terminals of the resistor. The battery keeps pumping to ensure this difference is kept. When one of the sides is disconnected, the water can no longer leave and the water will keep rising until it is level with 9 volts.

Comment: But isnt it also directly connected to the plus side?

Comment: @MahNeh That is correct. It connected through the resistor. No current can flow so $I=0$. This means that the voltage drop over the resistor is zero and so the voltage at the out-terminal is the same as the voltage at the positive terminal of the battery.

Comment: I am talking about diagram B, where the switch is pressed. *the out-voltage reader is directly connected to ground (...) the out-voltage is at zero volt* I do not understand, the out voltage cant be zero if it is connected to the + side as well

Comment: @MahNeh Ah I thought you were talking about the released diagram. In diagram B the out-voltage is not *directly* connected to the positive terminal. There is a resistor in between. There could be a voltage difference over the resistor. And in fact, there *is* a voltage difference over the resistor. In this case exactly 9V such that one side of the resistor is at 9V and the other at zero volt.

Comment: @MahNeh, Voltage between the two ends of a resistor is related to the current through the resistor as described by Ohm's law.

Comment: @AccidentalTaylorExpansion that is quite unexpected, why does this magic happen here? Why isnt just a lower value of voltage after R due to the Ohms Law and is 0 instead ?

Comment: @MahNeh Maybe this simulation will make it more clear https://tinyurl.com/2paraoek

Comment: I think it is bc of KVL bc would have battery voltage = -Voltage drop so it goes 0 to 9 and 9 to 0 (like the simulation, thanks). I find this weird..